# What 1980's movie was the first to have an official montage?

Tags: first-appearance

We all know that many of the 1980's movies were famous for their montages with cheesy music going on in the background and random clips of the main characters doing things (cleaning up, playing games, etc.)

What was the **first** 1980's movie to do this?

Comment: Is this a trick question?  A classic cheesy music montage example is from [Rocky (1976)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DP3MFBzMH2o).

Comment: Downvoted for a couple reasons. Why an 80s movie? Why not first montage ever? Also, what is an "official" montage?

Comment: @SamTheBrand because that is what [tag:80s] movies were known for. Their montages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you'd be hard pressed to find any evidence of a *cliche 80s montage* earlier than the one from [Rocky](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DP3MFBzMH2o) in 1976.

Obviously the idea of a montage wasn't new, nor even the idea of a *training montage*, but Rocky did combine those two elements with cheesy inspirational synth music, and that precise style was imitated in underdog action films ad nauseum through the 80s.

Comment: 1976 should be made an honorary '80s year for this reason.

Comment: If you want an actual 80's example, you could always go with Rocky III, with Rocky and Apollo running on the beach... classic.